# Magento Parallelize downloads across hostnames

Tags: magento, parallel-processing

We have a problem at our domain and it is going really slow, without knowing what changed. When I look at

> tools.pingdom

I see they say we have ***"Parallelize downloads across hostnames"***. We only can not find what it exactly is or what we can do. It is about the domain Fooss.nl. It has gone up from a load time of 1,5 seconds to 8 seconds.

Would be great if someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

You are serving resources from two different hostnames which increases parallelization of downloads.

If you host your static files using a CDN, your CDN may support serving these resources from more than one hostname. Contact your CDN to find out.

**Recommendations**

```
Balance parallelizable resources across hostnames.
Prevent external JS from blocking parallel downloads.
Always serve a resource from the same hostname.
```

For more info go to :

**https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rtt#ParallelizeDownloads**

Comment: Dear Slimshadddyy, thanks for your reply. At the moment we are not using a cdn, we get everything from our own hosting account. It is going wrong at http://www.fooss.nl, the strange thing is that it is going ok at http://www.loungeset.nl (same server and same coding), any ideas?